# Class referenced in the manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest, android-library

### Class referenced in the manifest, `com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity`, was not found in the project or the libraries.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLUm5.png)

Comment: You do not have a class with that fully-qualified class name in your project. Either remove the `<activity>` element or add that class.

Comment: did you add dependency to this library in app.gradle file.  if yes did you sync your code?

Comment: yes I already added depedency on the gradle section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to `file-> Invalidate Caches and Restart`

it works for me

[image]

Comment: Great tip. Unfortunately it didn't help in my case: 
`<receiver android:name="com.google.android.voicesearch.DetailsReceiver" android:exported="true" >`